# Abort Long Running Method

Tags: .net, abort

This is in a loop

Occasionally aPdf.Save will take minutes.

What I would like to to set time limit like 60 seconds.
If it takes longer just set succUpdate = false; and continue

```
try
{
    aPdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(docPathIn);
    // aPdf.Save will just hang some times and not throw an exception
    // if is runs more than 60 seconds I would like to give up and move to the next document
    aPdf.Save(MyDirOut + nativeXPSnew, Aspose.Pdf.SaveFormat.Xps);
    succUpdate = true;
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
    succUpdate = true;
}
finally
{
    aPdf = null;
}
```

Comment: I would instead try to focus (and probably complain to them) on why aspose hangs your application instead

Comment: @HighCore OK I also want to use this for long running that does not hang.

Comment: You cannot abort a big chunk of code like that safely.  You can only ignore that it is still running.